# ! Missing $ inserted.<inserted text>$ \end{multline}

Tags: amsmath, multline, missing

```
\nabla L(\boldsymbol {\beta})=
\mbox{
\Large
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial r_1}{\partial\beta_1}\\
\frac{\partial r_1}{\partial\beta_2}\\
\vdots \\
\frac{\partial r_1}{\partial\beta_n}
\end{pmatrix}
} \cdot
r_1(\boldsymbol{\beta}) + \cdots +
\mbox{
\Large
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial r_m}{\partial\beta_1}\\
\frac{\partial r_m}{\partial\beta_2}\\
\vdots \\
\frac{\partial r_m}{\partial\beta_n}
\end{pmatrix}
}\cdot
r_m(\boldsymbol{\beta}) = \\
= \mbox{
\Large
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial r_1}{\partial\beta_1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial r_m}{\partial\beta_1}\\
\frac{\partial r_1}{\partial\beta_2} & \cdots & \frac{\partial r_m}{\partial\beta_2}\\
\vdots & \huge{\ddots} & \vdots\\
\frac{\partial r_1}{\partial\beta_n} & \cdots & \frac{\partial r_m}{\partial\beta_n}
\end{pmatrix}
}
\mbox{
\large
\begin{pmatrix}
r_1(\boldsymbol{\beta})\\[1.4ex]
r_2(\boldsymbol{\beta})\\[1.4ex]
\huge{\vdots}\\[1.4ex]
r_m(\boldsymbol{\beta})
\end{pmatrix}
}
=J_{\boldsymbol{r}}(\boldsymbol{\beta}) ^{\mathrm{T}} \boldsymbol{r} (\boldsymbol{\beta})
\end{multline} \\
```

I don't know how to fix the problem. Actually I don't know where I am supposed to insert that $.

Comment: The TeX error will tell you the line number, and the last thing before the line break in the error is where in that line the error occurs.  But have you tried deleting various parts of this to isolate what's causing the problem?  Offhand, my guess would be the `mbox` is putting you into text mode, and then you do math stuff.  And the `\\ ` at the end is bad.

Comment: But welcome to TeX.SX. You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4):

The argument of `\mbox` is processed in text mode, not math mode, by default. Hence all the warning messages, as the `pmatrix` environments must be processed in math mode. The remedy? Get rid of all `\mbox` and all `\large`, `\Large`, and `\huge` statements. Really!

I'd also replace the `multline` environment with a combined `equation`/`aligned[b]` environment.

If you want larger fraction terms, use `\dfrac` instead of `\frac`; see equation (2) in the following screenshot. That said, I think you'd be better off switching to inline-fraction notation for the Jacobian terms; see equation (3) below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\begin{document} 

%% first version: \frac, \arraystretch=1.333
\begin{equation}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.333}
\begin{aligned}[b]
\nabla L(\bm {\beta})
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial r_1}{\partial\beta_1}\\
\frac{\partial r_1}{\partial\beta_2}\\
\vdots \\
\frac{\partial r_1}{\partial\beta_n}
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
r_1(\bm{\beta}) 
+ \dots +
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial r_m}{\partial\beta_1}\\
\frac{\partial r_m}{\partial\beta_2}\\
\vdots \\
\frac{\partial r_m}{\partial\beta_n}
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
r_m(\bm{\beta}) \\
&= 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial r_1}{\partial\beta_1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial r_m}{\partial\beta_1}\\
\frac{\partial r_1}{\partial\beta_2} & \cdots & \frac{\partial r_m}{\partial\beta_2}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\frac{\partial r_1}{\partial\beta_n} & \cdots & \frac{\partial r_m}{\partial\beta_n}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
r_1(\bm{\beta})\\
r_2(\bm{\beta})\\
\vdots\\
r_m(\bm{\beta})
\end{pmatrix}
=J_{\bm{r}}(\bm{\beta}) ^{\mathrm{T}} \bm{r} (\bm{\beta})
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\hrule
\medskip

%% second version: \dfrac, \arraystretch=1.75
\begin{equation}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.75}
\begin{aligned}[b]
\nabla L(\bm {\beta})
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial r_1}{\partial\beta_1}\\
\dfrac{\partial r_1}{\partial\beta_2}\\
\vdots \\
\dfrac{\partial r_1}{\partial\beta_n}
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
r_1(\bm{\beta}) 
+ \dots +
\begin{pmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial r_m}{\partial\beta_1}\\
\dfrac{\partial r_m}{\partial\beta_2}\\
\vdots \\
\dfrac{\partial r_m}{\partial\beta_n}
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
r_m(\bm{\beta}) \\
&= 
\begin{pmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial r_1}{\partial\beta_1} & \cdots & \dfrac{\partial r_m}{\partial\beta_1}\\
\dfrac{\partial r_1}{\partial\beta_2} & \cdots & \dfrac{\partial r_m}{\partial\beta_2}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\dfrac{\partial r_1}{\partial\beta_n} & \cdots & \dfrac{\partial r_m}{\partial\beta_n}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
r_1(\bm{\beta})\\
r_2(\bm{\beta})\\
\vdots\\
r_m(\bm{\beta})
\end{pmatrix}
=J_{\bm{r}}(\bm{\beta}) ^{\mathrm{T}} \bm{r} (\bm{\beta})
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\hrule


%% third version: inline-style fraction notation, \arraystretch=1.0 (the default)
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[b]
\nabla L(\bm {\beta})
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
\partial r_1/\partial\beta_1 \\
\partial r_1/\partial\beta_2 \\
\vdots \\
\partial r_1/\partial\beta_n
\end{pmatrix}
r_1(\bm{\beta}) 
+ \dots +
\begin{pmatrix}
\partial r_m/\partial\beta_1\\
\partial r_m/\partial\beta_2\\
\vdots \\
\partial r_m/\partial\beta_n
\end{pmatrix}
r_m(\bm{\beta}) \\
&= 
\begin{pmatrix}
\partial r_1/\partial\beta_1 & \cdots & \partial r_m/\partial\beta_1\\
\partial r_1/\partial\beta_2 & \cdots & \partial r_m/\partial\beta_2\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\partial r_1/\partial\beta_n & \cdots & \partial r_m/\partial\beta_n
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
r_1(\bm{\beta})\\
r_2(\bm{\beta})\\
\vdots\\
r_m(\bm{\beta})
\end{pmatrix}
=J_{\bm{r}}(\bm{\beta}) ^{\mathrm{T}} \bm{r} (\bm{\beta})
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```